# How to create a view that can be useed on multiple views?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How to create a view that can be used on multiple views ?

All the views using single layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Partial View](http://mvc4beginner.com/Tutorial/MVC-Partial-Views.html) to create a template that you can use in different parent views.